# Recalculate discounts in prestashop cart

Tags: prestashop, shopping-cart, prestashop-1.7, discount

I'm working on prestashop shop where are used coupon with % discounts. We don't want to use coupons on products on sale but still want to buy products on sale and normal products in the same cart. I want to recalculate discounts in cart and order to apply only on non-sale products. I need help which file I should edit or where add functions to do it.

Comment: It is not a very difficult modification but requires a good knowledge and understanding of Prestashop cart price calculation. We developed something similar for some client that needed a very specific behaviour. In your case, pretty common, my suggestion is to buy a module that already does allow you to create cart rules that doesn't apply on discounted products, it will do the override for you and you will save a lot of time and tests.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [module](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/) that adds dedicated cart rules or customer-related specific prices on the products you are interested in when customer changes his cart or validate the order.
There are plenty of native Prestashop [hooks](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/) you can use for that so you don't need tweaking with the core.

Keep in mind that there are a lot of "advanced cart rules" modules out there, so consider having a look before reinventing the wheel.